# DataGridTextColumn Popup

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Как можно реализовать, чтобы popup появлялся только при наведении курсора мышки?

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="0.7*" Binding="{Binding UserFullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="ФИО" />
            <Popup IsOpen="True" 
                   PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridColumnHeader}, Path=PlacementTarget}" AllowsTransparency="True">
                <TextBox Text="" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Поиск по ФИО:" Width="180"/>
            </Popup>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Используйте не Popup, а ToolTip

Comment: ToolTip исчезает)) Я не могу начать писать в TextBox-e. Потому что фокус с Header уходит.